# Removing the close button (the X in the top-right corner) - in dialog box created using dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to remove the close button (the X in the top-right corner) on a dialog box created using dojo? I came across **dlg.closeButtonNode.style.display='none';** but it didn't work. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that doesn't work because your dialog instance isn't assign to a var named "dlg" but i can't be sure because you didn't post any code. Otherwise this should work. But there is an easier way to accomplish this, just by using CSS.

```
.dijitDialogCloseIcon {
    display: none;
}
```

That's all assuming you can't change your dialog instance otherwise you really should use the "closable" property of the dijit itself to disable closing of the dialog. Edit: As Ken in the comments pointed out, it's the preferred way since it also disables the handling of the escapekey. Examples:

Programmatic:

```
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
    myDialog = new Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px",
        closable: false // here
    });
});
```

Declaritive:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myDialog" data-dojo-props="closable:false"></div>
```

Comment: Setting `closable` to `false` is certainly the preferred way, since that will also disable handling of the escape key.  Note that it's only supported in Dojo 1.9 and 1.10 though.

Comment: absolutely correct, i'll add that to my answer for clarity. thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer... out of curiosity, is this anywhere on the docs as I could not find it anywhere?